# Getting undefined method `builder_photo' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, paperclip, grails-controller

I have a Builder profile image which is stored in Database table Builders.

I want to show the `current_user` image that is builder profile image in the navigation bar.

Sp I used.

`<%= image_tag(@builder.builder_photo.url, class: 'builder-img') %>`

This shows correct profile image in

- http://localhost:3000/api/v1/builders/:id/edit

but on other pages it showing an error

> undefined method `builder_photo' for nil:NilClass

I am new to rails. Please someone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most common error you can find in rails. Anytime you see this format:
`undefined method * builder_photo* for nil:NilClass`, it means @builder is nil (and nil don't have the `builder_photo` method, of course).
Where is this @builder variable defined?

Normally you setting variable like this in the controller file, for example:

```
class CarsController < BaseController
  def index
    @builder = Builder.new(a: 1, b: 2)
  end
end
```

Comment: My builder is defined in app/controllers/api/v1/builders_controller.rb but i want the builder_upload in every page   def edit
    @builder = Api::V1::Builder.find(params[:id])

  end and this is my controller method

Comment: you have to define this @builder in all the actions (pages) that you need it.

Comment: the issue was with my image tag. i was using @builder.builder_photo.url  which was returning nil. But I should have used current_user['builder_photo']. Now its fixed